# Docker swarm node left gossip cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm cluster with 3 leaders and 5 workers. Recently I encountered leaving some nodes from cluster. nodes leave and join cluster after couple of seconds
This is the logs I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJEm.png)

thank you for response guys